# How can it be physically justified that the energy is conserved for the solution of wave equation with Neumann boundary condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I have learned that the IBVP: $$u_{tt}-c^{2}u_{xx}=0,$$ $$u(x,0)=f(x),\,u_{t}(x,0)=g(x),$$ $$u_{x}(0,t)=u_{x}(L,t)=0$$

has the unique solution $\displaystyle u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(A_{0}+B_{0}t)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[A_{n}\cos(\omega_{n}t)+B_{n}\sin(\omega_{n})t]\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$ with $\displaystyle A_{n}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx,\,n=0,1,2,\cdots$, $\displaystyle B_{n}=\frac{2}{\omega_{n}L}\int_{0}^{L}g(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx,\,n=1,2,3\cdots$ and $\displaystyle B_{0}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}g(x)dx$ if some assumptions on $f$ and $g$ are met.

Also, by differentiating $\displaystyle e(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L}[u_{t}^{2}(x,t)+c^{2}u_{x}^{2}(x,t)]dx$, the quantity known as **energy**, I understood that $e'(t)=0$ hence the energy is conserved for this problem. However, the solution implies that the zeroth-order term is a linear function of $t$ so the solution grows as $t\rightarrow\infty$. This makes me confused about how the conservation of energy should be intuitively (or physically) interpreted (in fact, higher-order terms essentially represent oscillation so I think they are not of problem).

How can the conservation of energy be interpreted when the solution seems to keep increase as time increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing applies to an object in inertial movement. Its position in space is $u = u_0 + v t$ which is unbounded, but its kinetic energy $m v^2/2$ is constant. The reason is that only the derivative with respect to time appears in the energy.

Comment: Then in the solution formula, the term $B_{0}t$ can be just interpreted as sort of translation, irrelevant to energy?

Comment: I'm not a physicist but yes I think so. It is inertial motion.